# Mongoid document persistence after find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, mongodb, model, mongoid

I having trouble persisting my documents in mongoid.  I have the following code fragment in my controller:

```
params[:user][:residence_attributes][:locations_attributes].each do |num,location_attributes|
  zipcode = Location.find(location_attributes[:id])

  if !zipcode.update_attributes(location_attributes)
    puts "fail"
    fail = true
  end

  puts "zipcode again #{zipcode}"
  puts "zipcode number #{zipcode.number}"
  puts "zipcodes = #{Zipcode.count}" 
  zipcode = Zipcode.find(@user.residence.locations[0].id)
  puts "zipcode again #{zipcode}"
  puts "zipcode number #{zipcode.number}"
  puts "zipcodes = #{Zipcode.count}" 
  zipcode = Zipcode.find(@user.residence.locations[0].id)
  puts "zipcode again #{zipcode}"
  puts "zipcode number #{zipcode.number}"
  puts "zipcodes = #{Zipcode.count}" 
end
```

And it yields the following output:

```
zipcode again #<Zipcode:0x000000063826a0>
zipcode number 11210
zipcodes = 1
zipcode again #<Zipcode:0x00000006348860>
zipcode number 
zipcodes = 1
zipcode again #<Zipcode:0x00000006340ef8>
zipcode number 
zipcodes = 1
```

So the question is why does the zipcode id change when I find the document the second and third time?

This is a problem because the document does not persist.

I have the following models:

```
class Zipcode < Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  attr_accessible :number
  attr_accessor :number

  validates_presence_of :number
  validate :check_zipcode
end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude
  belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
end

class UserResidence
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :locations, as: :locatable

  embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :residence

  attr_accessible :locations_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, autosave: true

  #validates_presence_of :locations
  #validates :locations, :length => {:minimum => 1}
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

are you saving the document?

try to set autosave to true

see: 
    http://mongoid.org/docs/upgrading.html
(search on the page for autosave)

Comment: Autosave is true, I'll update the post with user_residence model.  Either way, I am updating the Zipcode directly so would I still need autosave?

Comment: there's also a related Bug in Mongoid:   https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1198

Comment: Is the bug still in mongoid 2.2.1? because that's the version I'm using

Comment: durran closed the issue in b064b05 September 10, 2011 -- milestone for it was 2.2.1 ... hmm... maybe you should report it as regression?

Answer (score 0):

As per http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/nested_attributes.html you need to set `autosave: true` on `has_many :locations`.

```
has_many :locations, as: :locatable, autosave: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
```